# Formating numbers with %1$,.2f

Tags: java

I am using

```
public static String displayNumberAmount(Number amount, Locale locale) {
    String.format(locale, "%1$,.2f", amount);
}
```

to format my numbers in locale and 2 decimals.

If i have number 1032 it will be correctly formatted into the 1 032,00
BUT if I have number lower than 1000, for example 890, it will be formatted as 890 (and I need those 2 decimals always)

in the object, those values are stored as BigDecimals, like

```
BigDecimal val = object.getAmount();
String formattedVal = displayNumberAmount(val, myLocale);
```

Can you tell me why?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you give the exact code (the one you show doesn't use the returned value) and the locale ?

Comment: my BigDecimal val is 932. My locale is French.

Comment: Well, I just tried `Number amount = new BigDecimal(832);System.out.println(String.format(Locale.FRENCH, "%1$,.2f", amount));`. Do you use the return of `format` ?

Comment: I would use double instead of Number. Idk... I'm Too used to C/C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. This is my test:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Tester{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("999 " + displayNumberAmount(new BigDecimal(999.99), Locale.FRENCH));
        System.out.println("1000 " + displayNumberAmount(new BigDecimal(1000.99), Locale.FRENCH));
        System.out.println("1001 " + displayNumberAmount(new BigDecimal(1001.99), Locale.FRENCH));
    }

    public static String displayNumberAmount(Number amount, Locale locale) {
        return String.format(locale, "%1$,.2f", amount);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static String displayNumberAmount(Number amount, Locale locale) {
    return String.format(locale, "%1$,.2f", amount);
}
```

'return' statement is missing.

Comment: I pointed that in comments, but that's not the explanation of OP's problem.